# Dark theme not showing table values in my Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablelayout, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

My Android app works well when the device is in light mode but when changed the dark mode, the table values no longer show.

What may be wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the issue. I used custom styling in my table layout and set the background color of the the custom table border to white. Hence, it was always white

I have now resolved the issue by setting the color of the border to a "Theme" resource (sth like that) where I set it's value to black for light mode and white for dark mode